# Is there a matrix decomposition $P = AA^{+}$, given P?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Suppose one could experimentally obtain $P$, a $N\times N$ matrix.

Is there a way to decompose this into two matrices $AA^{+}$, where $A$ is $N\times M$ and $A^{+}$ is the pseudo-inverse of $A$?

In the problem, we can be sure that $M << N$.

Answer (score 0):

If $A^+$ is the inverse in the usual sense (**A** is invertible) then $AA^+=I$ otherwise we have: $AA^+A=A$ therefore, if **P** could have been presented that way, we would have had: $PA=A$

Comment: I guess one could minimize the difference between some guess matrix and P times the guess matrix.  When the difference is a zero matrix, we have the right A matrix.  Not sure if that's any easier than the original problem statement.  Thanks, though.